# Does rel="nofollow" link helps in SEO

Tags: seo, pagerank, links

I have read that links to rel="nofollow" doesn't help in pagerank or SEO.

I used google webmaster tool to find out the external links pointing to my website.

In results i found some links from posted in facebook too with rel="nofollow". Now I have been confused that whether those links from facebooks are helping to promote my Pagerank and SEO or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Page A links to Page B with a nofollow link, no PageRank will be passed from A to B.

That said, don't forget that the whole purpose of SEO is to get visitors. If Page A can help Page B get visitors, even if it doesn't pass PageRank, then the link is doing its job.

Comment: Exactly. If Google linked to you from its homepage your traffic would skyrocket, regardless of whether it was nofollow.

Comment: rel=nofollow is more about clearly stating intent. Given their recent algorithms which further punish linkfarms/backlinks/irrelevant content networks, it's undoubtedly good etiquette to use rel=nofollow where appropriate. When blogging, I always rel=nofollow URLs which I may be linking to but don't consider necessarily reputable or worthy of some 'linkjuice'. It's a case-by-case consideration; sometimes I might be linking to a common or relevant keyword and don't wish to diminish internal links or links to our own sites for the same terms or in the same context / paragraph / page.

Answer (score 0):

I use both dofollow and nofollow in my SEO campaign.  Both have value but should be used differently.  Let's say I have a Facebook Fan Page with a keyword/phrase I want to rank for.  There is no way that Facebook will help push my website up on the SERPs when it comes to Google juice.  However, in a round about way it does!  Facebook has a pagerank of 10 and is nofollow.  So no juice.  But if promoted correctly that Facebook Fan Page will drive traffic to your website because it will rank high in the SERPs.

It is not that hard to have a Facebook Fan Page rank well in the SERPs quickly.  This means that you will have a presence on that page targeting your keywords.  That presence will be reflected in more traffic.  That traffic will help push your website/blog high in the SERPs.

On the other hand, you could create and develop a blog on Wordpres.com which is a dofollow and has a pagerank of 9.  If you build unique and interesting content on that blog with a link to your website you will get Google Juice from that link.  As with the Facebook Fan Page mentioned above it is possible for your Wordpress blog to grab one of the positions on the first page of the SERPs.

In essence, you may have 3 different properties pop up on the 1st page!

Many people do not understand how powerful blogs, Facebook, Twitter and Tumblr can be.  If done correctly you can dominate the SERPs for your keyword.  Note that some keywords are so competitive that it could take a long time.

In sum, both dofollow and nofollow have their own uses.  Lastly you can have a dofollow pushing juice to either a nofollow or another dofollow property.  One you place a nofollow into the mix the juice stops flowing from one property to another.

Answer (score 0):

The no follow does not pass page rank but as far the ranking is concerned the no follow links do help as it creates a diversity in the link profile.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 10, 2019, Google announced to start treating rel=nofollow as 'hint' which means in some cases it may decide to count it or may also use it as an advantage to rank some sites. Read more [here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/09/evolving-nofollow-new-ways-to-identify.html).